# this sparkcontext is an existing one

Tags: pyspark

I am setting up a `SparkSession` using

```python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('nlp').getOrCreate()
```

But I am getting an error:

```python
# This SparkContext may be an existing one.
```

Comment: Check that this code is not called twice or there is no other place where spark is initialized.

Comment: how to check where the spark is initialized and how can i reset it.  I am using Mac.

Comment: When running an **interactive** session with `physpark`, a `spark` Python variable is automatically created and mapped to an _immutable_ Scala object of the same name, managing the session. When running a **batch** job with `spark-submit` you have to explicitly create the session. Bottom line: check whether `spark` is defined, and if not, then create the session.